# Find equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

A is set of all propositional expressions on the propositions p1 , p2 , . . . , pn.
Relation R on A is defined as (P, Q) ∈ R if P ↔ Q is a tautology.
I think it is an equivalence relation, what should be its equivalence classes?

Comment: I expect $[P]$ is the collection of propositional expressions that have the same truth table as $P$.

Comment: @Crostul I didn't get it!